# What does "layer units" mean?

Tags: qgis, heat-map, density

I created a Shapefile from Google Earth (kmz) consisting of a set of points which I had used as a layer for Heatmap analysis.

I opened the kmz file in QGIS and utilized the heatmap plug-in and it has `8 layer units` as the default radius.

Can anybody enlighten me what does this 8 layer units mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_heatmap.html) says

> Radius: Is used to specify the heatmap search radius (or kernel
>   bandwidth) in meters or map units. The radius specifies the distance
>   around a point at which the influence of the point will be felt.
>   Larger values result in greater smoothing, but smaller values may show
>   finer details and variation in point density.

So if your layer has a projection system in meters, it means the radius of influence around each point will be 8 meters. If it is in feet, the radius of influence will be 8 feet... and if the dataset is not projected but it rather in lat-long, it will be 8 degrees - which is huge.